# tracking changes to a directory, including program responsible for change

Tags: windows-xp, monitoring

On my external hard drive, directories keep appearing. Their names are random strings of numbers and letter, and they all contain an empty folder called "1042".  My security software doesn't find any viruses anywhere on my machine, so I'm assuming that it's some legitimate but buggy software.

Anyways, I'd like to find out what program is doing it, so I need some tool that can monitor the root directory of the drive for changes, and log not only what changes occured but what program performed the modifications.  I've found a few freeware programs that track changes, but none that can tell me the crucial piece of information, what program did the changing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Process monitor may be able to do it

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

but it would have to be running when the folder is created, and would require a bit of detective work on your part, the log could be huge because it monitors all file activity.

Comment: It can be filtered so it'll track activity only on specific processes or objects. Yes the log'll get big, but it will tell you what's doing what.